# WampServer Hosting

Tags: hosting, wampserver

about 6 months ago I got into coding, and I've always wanted to start my own game just for fun on the side.

I have wampserver on my computer, and was wondering if that server could publicly host things on the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

- Make sure your server is available on the internet. If you have a router or firewall you may need to open it up.
- If you want to have a domain name you need to register that.
- If your ISP can give you a static IP address then ask for that.
- Whether you have a static IP or a dynamic one then you can use a service such as [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/services/dns/dyndns/) to link the domain name to the IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use your WAMPserver to allow people to publicly access your site.

From some quick googling, I didn't find any instructions, just that it was possible.

Comment: Thank you very much -- I'd vote you up but I don't have enough reputation. However, instructions would be wonderful, or at least a link to instructions!

Answer (score 0):

I just put a wamp server up on a box in my house just for funsies. 
[Here is a wampserver forum post with links to the info you seek.](http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,70777,70777) 
Here is the basic rundown though: 
Open up your router to port 80 and forward it to the box you are serving on. 
Get setup on a DNS server, I used [freedns.afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org).
In wamp you are gonna set apache to use virtual hosts (this is in the link). 
After that you should be cool.